# Skip most contacted contacts when retrieving all contacts

Tags: c#, gdata, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I get all the gmail account contact by following code.

```
try
{
    Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> Contacts = contactRequest.GetContacts();
    Contact entity;     //local entity
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
    foreach (Google.Contacts.Contact objContact in Contacts.Entries)
    {
        try
        {
            entity = new Contact();
            entity.AddrType = (int)GroupTypes.LocalContact;
            entity.UserID = DataHelper.EmployeeID;
            entity.GmailContactId = objContact.Id;
            entity.GmailContactEtag = objContact.ETag;
            entity.FirstName = objContact.Name.FullName;
            contactList.Add(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    return contactList;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

Above code returns all the contacts including contacts of Most Contacted and Other Contacts folder. I just need to get contacts of My Contacts and Custom Groups(user created).
Please suggest appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Contact API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/), you can use the [`group`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference) parameter in the request.

> `group` Constrains the results to only the contacts belonging to the group specified. Value of this parameter specifies group ID (see also: [`gContact:groupMembershipInfo`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#groupMembershipInfo)).